# Error Compile Error: Invalid bind expression Query Help

Tags: soql

new to apex and visualforce. I am trying to create a visualforce page that displays selected products and their locations for an order. Currently I am able to display the products selected for the order, however I can not figure out how to filter my query down to display only the product locations specific to the current order. I added the Shipment__c query to help look for products that are in shipments however I am getting the following error:

> Error: Compile Error: Invalid bind expression type of Shipment__c for Id field of SObject Product2 at line 8 column 17

Any help would be appreciated.

My class is as follows:

```
public with sharing class ProductMovements {

Shipment__c[] sp = [Select (Select Project_Task__r.GMBLASERP__Product__r.Id From Shipment_Lines__r) From Shipment__c ];

Product2[] pp = [SELECT Id FROM Product2 WHERE Id IN :sp];

     public AggregateResult[] gim {
        get {
            return [SELECT GMBLASERP__Product__r.name name, GMBLASERP__Location__r.name location, SUM(GMBLASERP__Quantity__c) sum
                                                    FROM GMBLASERP__Inventory_Movement_Cube__c
                                                    WHERE GMBLASERP__Product__c IN :pp
                                                    GROUP BY GMBLASERP__Product__r.name, GMBLASERP__Location__r.name];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's only dynamic soql if you build out query strings and use `Database.query`. You do none of that here, using only static queries. As such, I have removed the `[dynamic-soql]` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to unpack the Product2Ids from the first SOQL query to then use them in a binding expression.

E.g.

```
Set<Id> product2Ids = new Set<Id>();
for(Shipment__c sp : [Select (Select Project_Task__r.GMBLASERP__Product__r.Id From Shipment_Lines__r) From Shipment__c ]) {
    product2Ids.add(sp.Project_Task__r.GMBLASERP__Product__r.Id);
}
Product2[] pp = [SELECT Id FROM Product2 WHERE Id IN :product2Ids];
```

That said, you could probably completely skip the `Shipment__c` records and go straight to the `Shipment_Lines__c` records with:

```
Select Project_Task__r.GMBLASERP__Product__r.Id From Shipment_Lines__c
```

If you can get it all the way down to whatever `GMBLASERP__Product__c` is it could make the query much simpler. You will likely need to add a where clause, but it should be much more efficient.